# Bending an Object into a Sphere

Tags: objects

Im using polyhedrons created only from hexa- and pentagons to simulate tiles on a planetlike gameboard, to make my board look like a planet and not an polyhedron. I want to make it spherical while still keeping the tiles mostly intact, what would a good approch be?

I cant use subdivision surface or bevel because that only rounds out the edges and leaves the faces mostly flat. The Solution probably involes subdividing the faces and then telling the object to try to become a sphere, which is the part i dont know how to do.

The polyhedron i use looks like [this](https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10cD)

Comment: I followed the two approaches but for both I encountered a problem. As suggested I clean up the sharps and then subdivide a few times. Then I transform it into a sphere and at last I want to cut out the single tiles. I select the faces of the tile I want to separate but after finishing one tile it appears as if the tile is somewhat warped.
But the first answer shows perfectly fine tiles with no odd structures. What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

- Just to tidy up, select all edges, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Data > 'Clear Sharp'
- Assign a Subdivision Surface modifier with the 'Simple' option (1 or 2 levels)
- Assign a Cast modifier, 'Sphere' option, Factor: 1

[image]

You can apply the modifiers to bake them into the mesh, if/when you need to, (in order, top to bottom)..

You can assign an 'Edge Split' modifier above the others, if you need to split out the surface tiles,
and apply it followed by  <kbd>P</kbd> > separate by Loose Parts if you need the tiles to be separate objects

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need more geometry to have something to deform first so Subsurf modifier will be needed. You will need a few subdivisions. Once it is applied, you can go into Edit Mode(<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all(<kbd>a</kbd>) and transform it to sphere(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

[image: Transform to Sphere]