# Sphere by a Goldberg polyhedron

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, faces

Hellor everyone,

this is my first question on this forum so I apologize if am unaware of some customs.

I thought about creating a Goldberg polyhedron in Blender but found a website

https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10cD

that let's me create custom polyhedrons.

My goal was to create a sphere that has several hexagonal and pentagonal elements on the surface but I do not know how to shape these polyhedrons from the website to spheres.

One approach I could imagine would be to only select the faces and give them a little curve until all faces form a ball. But I wonder whether the vertices of this polyhedron even lay on a sphere (the models on the website seem somewhat "not round") so I would not end up with a "round" but bumpy modell.

Another approach could be to use a bigger sphere and extrude the vertices from the polyhedron until they lay on the spheres surface. These intersection point then could be used to create hexagonal and pentagonal elements on the sphere's surface.

But I don't know whether these approaches are even somewhat viable.

Does anyone have a solution for this (maybe a completely different approach)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are builtin primitives for most regular solids, don't those work for you? Or are you talking about animating a morphing the shape to a sphere?

Comment: I want to create a game in Unity using the sphere as the floor. The hexagonal and pentagonal elements are part of the movement system. Of course I could use the polyhedron models from the website or the primitives of Blender, but I need to project their faces onty a sphere. Therefore my question on how to do this: with either curving the faces so I end up with a sphere (if possible) or project the vertices of the polyhedron onto a sphere and recreate the faces with a curve causes by the spheres surface.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124938/bending-an-object-into-a-sphere I think I will try the steps in this post.